# Why do I not need a private key to decode my amazon JWT?

Tags: jwt, rsa, amazon-cognito

I've been reading that when using Amazon Cognito for verification and for JWT tokens, all I need to decode the signature is the public key. However, if that's true, I would think that makes it less secure since someone could change their jwt and then alter the signature, and my decoding on the API side would not know the difference since I do not know the private key, and the public key is, well, public, and can be used to generate a signature.

Can anyone help clarify this?

Comment: The public key is used to _verify_ (not decode) a signature, but it is impossible to create (generate) a valid signature without the private key, which should be kept private, which is why it was given the name private key in the first place, and that prevents anyone else from creating signatures for falsified data. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the use of [Asymmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (with private/public key pairs), no-one can modify the token and add a signature to it that is accepted by someone using the public key of the original sender.

The content inside a token is public and be access by anyone who has it, that is why you should not store GDPR sensitive data inside it. But still, no-one can generate new tokens without a copy of the private key.

It can also be wise to do regular key-rotation, where you on a regular basis replace the private key with a new one.